# Down casting an instance of Base to a derived class with no members

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

I inherited (no pun intended) some code that has this:

```
class Base {
public:
    static Base* GetInstance() { 
        return pInstance; //static member (initialized as Singleton with new Base(); 
    }
    void Foo();
};


class Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {}
public:
    Bar();
};
```

And usage of it looks like this:

```
((Derived*)Base::GetInstance())->Bar();
```

Is this defined behavior?

It works on MSVC and I understand why it could be defined, but I don't know how to verify if it is (other than asking for some wisdom).

Comment: How is `pInstance` initialized?

Comment: Pick your favorite Singleton initialization pattern.

Comment: Updated comment, initialization with new Base

Comment: It is defined if pInstance's static type is derived.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. It accesses an object of type `Derived` that doesn't exist. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Igor is correct.  This code is depending on _undefined behavior_ to act a certain way.  In real-world scenarios, even without `Derived` adding members, this can fail.

Comment: Can someone point me to some reference on this?

Comment: [**basic.life/4**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#4) "The properties ascribed to objects and references throughout this document apply for a given object or reference only during its lifetime." Your program never starts a lifetime of any object of type `Derived`.